# Take data from an xls sheet and add them into python commands

Tags: python, automation, data-manipulation

I've been asked to create a Python script to automate a server deployment for 80 retail stores.

As part of this script, I have a secondary script that I call to change multiple values in 9 XML files, however, the values are unique for each store, so this script needs to be changed each time, but after I am gone, this is going to be done by semi /  non-technical people, so we don't want them to change the Python scripts directly for fear of breaking them.

This in mind, I would like to have these people input the store details into an XLS sheet, and a python file read this sheet and put the data it finds into the existing python script with the data to be changed.
The file will be 2 columns, with the required data in the 2nd one.

I'm sorry if this is a long explanation, but that is the gist of it. I'm using python 2.6. Does anyone have a clue about how I can do this? Or which language might be better for this. I also know Bash and Javascript.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity and the volume of your data 
for **small** [Openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), 
for **large** [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)